# Apache Spark 2.2: broadcast join not working when you already cache the dataframe which you want to broadcast

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I have mulitple large dataframes(around 30GB) called as and bs, a relatively small dataframe(around 500MB ~ 1GB) called spp.
I tried to cache spp into memory in order to avoid reading data from database or files multiple times.

But I find if I cache spp, the physical plan shows it won't use broadcast join even though spp is enclosed by broadcast function.
However, If I unpersist the spp, the plan shows it uses broadcast join.

Anyone familiar with this?

```scala
scala> spp.cache
res38: spp.type = [id: bigint, idPartner: int ... 41 more fields]

scala> val as = acs.join(broadcast(spp), $"idsegment" === $"idAdnetProductSegment")
as: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [idsegmentpartner: bigint, ssegmentsource: string ... 44 more fields]

scala> as.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*SortMergeJoin [idsegment#286L], [idAdnetProductSegment#91L], Inner
:- *Sort [idsegment#286L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(idsegment#286L, 200)
:     +- *Filter isnotnull(idsegment#286L)
:        +- HiveTableScan [idsegmentpartner#282L, ssegmentsource#287, idsegment#286L], CatalogRelation `default`.`tblcustomsegmentcore`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [idcustomsegment#281L, idsegmentpartner#282L, ssegmentpartner#283, skey#284, svalue#285, idsegment#286L, ssegmentsource#287, datecreate#288]
+- *Sort [idAdnetProductSegment#91L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(idAdnetProductSegment#91L, 200)
      +- *Filter isnotnull(idAdnetProductSegment#91L)
         +- InMemoryTableScan [id#87L, idPartner#88, idSegmentPartner#89, sSegmentSourceArray#90, idAdnetProductSegment#91L, idPartnerProduct#92L, idFeed#93, idGlobalProduct#94, sBrand#95, sSku#96, sOnlineID#97, sGTIN#98, sProductCategory#99, sAvailability#100, sCondition#101, sDescription#102, sImageLink#103, sLink#104, sTitle#105, sMPN#106, sPrice#107, sAgeGroup#108, sColor#109, dateExpiration#110, sGender#111, sItemGroupId#112, sGoogleProductCategory#113, sMaterial#114, sPattern#115, sProductType#116, sSalePrice#117, sSalePriceEffectiveDate#118, sShipping#119, sShippingWeight#120, sShippingSize#121, sUnmappedAttributeList#122, sStatus#123, createdBy#124, updatedBy#125, dateCreate#126, dateUpdated#127, sProductKeyName#128, sProductKeyValue#129], [isnotnull(idAdnetProductSegment#91L)]
               +- InMemoryRelation [id#87L, idPartner#88, idSegmentPartner#89, sSegmentSourceArray#90, idAdnetProductSegment#91L, idPartnerProduct#92L, idFeed#93, idGlobalProduct#94, sBrand#95, sSku#96, sOnlineID#97, sGTIN#98, sProductCategory#99, sAvailability#100, sCondition#101, sDescription#102, sImageLink#103, sLink#104, sTitle#105, sMPN#106, sPrice#107, sAgeGroup#108, sColor#109, dateExpiration#110, sGender#111, sItemGroupId#112, sGoogleProductCategory#113, sMaterial#114, sPattern#115, sProductType#116, sSalePrice#117, sSalePriceEffectiveDate#118, sShipping#119, sShippingWeight#120, sShippingSize#121, sUnmappedAttributeList#122, sStatus#123, createdBy#124, updatedBy#125, dateCreate#126, dateUpdated#127, sProductKeyName#128, sProductKeyValue#129], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                     +- *Scan JDBCRelation(tblSegmentPartnerProduct) [numPartitions=1] [id#87L,idPartner#88,idSegmentPartner#89,sSegmentSourceArray#90,idAdnetProductSegment#91L,idPartnerProduct#92L,idFeed#93,idGlobalProduct#94,sBrand#95,sSku#96,sOnlineID#97,sGTIN#98,sProductCategory#99,sAvailability#100,sCondition#101,sDescription#102,sImageLink#103,sLink#104,sTitle#105,sMPN#106,sPrice#107,sAgeGroup#108,sColor#109,dateExpiration#110,sGender#111,sItemGroupId#112,sGoogleProductCategory#113,sMaterial#114,sPattern#115,sProductType#116,sSalePrice#117,sSalePriceEffectiveDate#118,sShipping#119,sShippingWeight#120,sShippingSize#121,sUnmappedAttributeList#122,sStatus#123,createdBy#124,updatedBy#125,dateCreate#126,dateUpdated#127,sProductKeyName#128,sProductKeyValue#129] ReadSchema: struct<id:bigint,idPartner:int,idSegmentPartner:int,sSegmentSourceArray:string,idAdnetProductSegm...

scala> spp.unpersist
res40: spp.type = [id: bigint, idPartner: int ... 41 more fields]

scala> as.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*BroadcastHashJoin [idsegment#286L], [idAdnetProductSegment#91L], Inner, BuildRight
:- *Filter isnotnull(idsegment#286L)
:  +- HiveTableScan [idsegmentpartner#282L, ssegmentsource#287, idsegment#286L], CatalogRelation `default`.`tblcustomsegmentcore`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [idcustomsegment#281L, idsegmentpartner#282L, ssegmentpartner#283, skey#284, svalue#285, idsegment#286L, ssegmentsource#287, datecreate#288]
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[4, bigint, true]))
   +- *Scan JDBCRelation(tblSegmentPartnerProduct) [numPartitions=1] [id#87L,idPartner#88,idSegmentPartner#89,sSegmentSourceArray#90,idAdnetProductSegment#91L,idPartnerProduct#92L,idFeed#93,idGlobalProduct#94,sBrand#95,sSku#96,sOnlineID#97,sGTIN#98,sProductCategory#99,sAvailability#100,sCondition#101,sDescription#102,sImageLink#103,sLink#104,sTitle#105,sMPN#106,sPrice#107,sAgeGroup#108,sColor#109,dateExpiration#110,sGender#111,sItemGroupId#112,sGoogleProductCategory#113,sMaterial#114,sPattern#115,sProductType#116,sSalePrice#117,sSalePriceEffectiveDate#118,sShipping#119,sShippingWeight#120,sShippingSize#121,sUnmappedAttributeList#122,sStatus#123,createdBy#124,updatedBy#125,dateCreate#126,dateUpdated#127,sProductKeyName#128,sProductKeyValue#129] PushedFilters: [*IsNotNull(idAdnetProductSegment)], ReadSchema: struct<id:bigint,idPartner:int,idSegmentPartner:int,sSegmentSourceArray:string,idAdnetProductSegm...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when the Analyzed plan tries to use the cache data. It swallows the `ResolvedHint` information supplied by the user([code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/QueryExecution.scala#L65)).
If we try to do a `df.explain(true)`, we will see that hint is lost between Analyzed and optimized plan, which is where Spark tries to use the cached data. 
This issue has been fixed in the latest version of Spark(in multiple attempts).
latest jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27674 .
Code where the fix(to consider the hint when using cached tables) : https://github.com/apache/spark/blame/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/CacheManager.scala#L219

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. So which spark version will this be fixed in? And the weird thing is what I described above is not 100% the case. If I use another smaller dataframe than spp called xspp, xspp.cache.count before using broadcast function. The physical plan will show broadcast join instead of sortmerge join. But if I do spp.cache.count, the physical plan still shows sortmerge join. Do you know why?

Comment: If the size of the dataframe is less than `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`(defaukt 10 MB), spark decides to use broadcast join, no hint is required.

Comment: Thanks. It does the magic. looks like **broadcast** function does not 100% force the broadcast join. It should be used with `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`.